# Symfony 3 ClassNotFoundException al crear Bundle

Tags: symfony3, bundler

Hasta ahora había usado Symfony 2 y me acabo de pasar a la versión 3. La instalación es correcta y puedo ejecutar el emulador y ver la pantalla de bienvenida. El problema está al crear un Bundle. Creo el bundle como siempre, con console y siguiendo las indicaciones y se crea mi bundle; pero... todo se acabo ya no puedo hacer nada, no puedo correr el server, crear una base de datos, entidad, siempre me da el siguiente error:

> (1/1) ClassNotFoundException
>
> Attempted to load class "ServiciosBundle" from namespace
>   "ServiciosBundle".
>
> Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
>
> in AppKernel.php (line 19)
>
> at AppKernel->registerBundles()in Kernel.php (line 450)
>
> at Kernel->initializeBundles()in Kernel.php (line 116)
>
> at Kernel->boot()in Kernel.php (line 168)
>
> at Kernel->handle(object(Request))in app_dev.php (line 29)

**El archivo AppKernel.php**

```
    <?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new ServiciosBundle\ServiciosBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

            if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
            }
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

**El archivo ServiciosBundle.php**

```
<?php

namespace ServiciosBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class ServiciosBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes enseñarnos tu fichero `AppKernel.php` ??

Comment: ¿Qué comando utilizó para iniciar el servidor de base de datos?

Comment: Revisa los nombres de la carpeta `ServiciosBundle` y el nombre del fichero `ServiciosBundle.php` por si hay algún error y no coinciden con el namespace. Prueba también a ejecutar `composer dumpautoload`, por si necesitaras volver a generar el autoload con nuevos namespaces.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Muriano me dió la pista para encontrar la solución. El problema es que al crear el Bundle no rellena el archivo vendor/composer/autoload_static.php. He añadido dos lineas guiandome por el bundle appBundle

Comment: @Josue pudieras crear una respuesta indicando más detalladamente como lo solucionaste??, por ejemplo indicando las líneas que agregaste en autoload_static.php, etc

Answer (score 1):

1. Edita `composer.json` y deja el campo `psr-4` como estaba inicialmente:

   ```
   "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
   ```
2. Lanza el siguiente comando desde el directorio del **proyecto**:

   ```
   composer dump-autoload
   ```
3. Edita `composer.json` y vuelve a añadir la información que tuvieras en:

   ```
   psr-4
   ```